# String match with option in Rust inside Some

Tags: rust

#### Problem description

I'm trying to match option string with match statement

```rust
let option_string = Some(String::from("Bob"));
    
match option_string {
  Some("Mike") => false,
  Some("Bob") => true,
  _ => false,
}
```

And, obviously, got an error `expected struct 'String, found '&str'`.

I tried to change it into string cast

```rust
Some("Mike".to_string()) => false

// Or
Some(String::from("Mike")) => false
```

But faced with a different error: `'fn' calls are not allowed in patterns`

---

The only working way is to place `Mike` into a variable before `Some`

```rust
let mike = String::from("Mike");

// and in match
Some(mike) => true,
```

#### Question

There is a more elegant way to match `String` but not string literals in `match` cases with `Option` value?

[I found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61001522/4079528) but it doesn't look elegant enough too. But is it only one possible way to not create extra variables or functions?

Comment: Maybe [`option_string.as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref)?

Comment: As a side note, in this contrived example, the expression `option_string.as_deref() == Some("Bob")` is superior to `match`.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm sure it's a simplified example to get the point across

Comment: @Finomnis It's still worth pointing out for folks landing here from a web search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```rust
let mike = String::from("Mike");

// and in match
Some(mike) => true,
```

This one is actually a misconception, I'm afraid. Variables are not allowed on the left side of a `match` expression. Having a name on the left side actually creates a new variable that contains the matched content. So the `mike` variable in your `match` clause matches **everything** and then carries the matched `String`; it is **not** the same variable as the outer `mike` variable.

Pay attention to this code example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let option_string = Some(String::from("Bob"));

    // Note how this line gets the compiler warning "unused variable".
    // You could leave this line out completely and it would still
    // compile.
    let mike = String::from("Mike");

    let result = match option_string {
        Some(mike) => {
            println!("Matched 'Mike': {}", mike);
            true
        }
        _ => false,
    };

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

```
Matched 'Mike': Bob
true
```

In general, you can only match against compile time constants. If you want to compare two variables, you have to use `if` instead.

---

### Solution

That said, your first example is quite easy to fix:

```rust
fn main() {
    let option_string = Some(String::from("Bob"));

    let result = match option_string.as_deref() {
        Some("Mike") => false,
        Some("Bob") => true,
        _ => false,
    };

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

```
true
```

Note the [`.as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref), which borrows an `Option<&str>` from the `Option<String>`, making it compatible with the string literal match expressions.